# AngularTS: Alernative to ComponentFactory

Tags: angular

I recently updated the angular version and packages of my old project to the latest version and I am currently working on updating deprecated uses. Below is the version details when running ng --version and I am using Webstorm 2021.3.3.

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.0
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.0
@schematics/angular             13.3.0
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.6.2
```

In the new Angular version, the use of component factory is deprecated. The API suggests using viewContainerRef.createComponent but it gives me an error saying it is deprecated. The following code shows a sample of what I am working on.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewContainerRef, Injector} from "@angular/core";
import { HelloWorldComponent } from "../../what-is-angular/hello-world/hello-world.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  makeDynamicComponent() {
    // const resultsComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloWorldComponent); // deprecated
    // const resultsComponentRef = resultsComponent.create(this.injector); // deprecated
    const resultComponentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(HelloWorldComponent, undefined, this.injector);
  }

}
```

What the error shows regarding the use of createComponent() and the parameter HelloWorldComponent:

```
Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative 
deprecated ViewContainerRef.createComponent<unknown>(     componentFactory: ComponentFactory<unknown>,     index?: number | undefined,     injector?: Injector | undefined,     projectableNodes?: any[][] | undefined,     ngModuleRef?: NgModuleRef<...> | undefined):    ComponentRef<...>
```

and

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof HelloWorldComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentFactory<unknown>'.   Type 'typeof HelloWorldComponent' is missing the following properties from type 'ComponentFactory<unknown>': selector, componentType, ngContentSelectors, inputs, and 2 more.
```

Am I not using the method correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecated way requires all the parameters as separate inputs. The new way requires just the first parameter as a separate input, then the rest are wrapped in an object.

All you need to do in the new way is this:

```js
this._viewContainerRef.createComponent(MyComponentComponent,{injector: this._injector});
```